# Joining two 2x4 as legs to two 1x6

Tags: wood, woodworking, wooden-furniture

I am building an elevated garden bed and I need to know what kind of joint will joint would make the structure least wobbly and provide most optimal load bearing capacity. I'm planning on joining two 2x4s as legs to two 1x6s. Much like what is happening right here:

[image]

Instead of a single 4x4, I have to use two separate boards of 2x4 untreated cedar (real dimensions: 1.5 x 3.5")

Comment: You mean 2 2x4s placed together to make a 4x4?  Only difference is you try to not place screws in the seam.

Comment: Yes, joining them on their long side, like this `||`, is one option. I was considering also doing an `L` shape of the 2x4 and joining them to the outer `L` shape of the `1x6`, i.e. an `LL` sort of.

Comment: Would go with the L shape, two together won't add anything that a single one will for weight strength.  One will hold the weight you want.  Main problem is with it being stable and not wobbly.

Comment: How do you define "best"? What is it you're looking for? Without knowing that, you'll just get some opinions and how will you know which one is "correct"?

Comment: That's fair enough. I am looking for the kind of join that would make the structure least wobbly and provide most optimal load bearing.

Comment: I'd need more details about your overall design. It's impossible to answer with what's here.

Comment: Both configurations will provide ample load bearing.  Wobble will need to be addressed by the strength of the joint attaching the legs to the side panels.